# Knapsack algorithm application

Tags: algorithm

Where else can we apply Knapsack problem apart from stealing gold and platinum bricks ? I tried to relate it with the stock market but some parameters didn't match like one for the weight. Even there is a time dimension  in stock market. Please let me know if there is any  real time application based on it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Applications

Comment: In the context on (Integral) Linear Programming, when using column generation algorithms, various formulations of Knapsack problems occur as subproblems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any real-world problems where you have resources with certain values and you want to waste as little as possible. Shipping containers, to be packed as efficiently as possible (this is about money). To cut large pieces of materials into smaller packages (paper, metal, wood-logs). To optimize portfolios (which shares and how many should you buy). Storing goods in warehouses. There are quite some problems that generalise the knapsack problem, and the solving-algorithms are there to help.